# UIToolbar inside UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uitoolbar

I'm trying to replicate the safari behavior. A uitoolbar inside a uiwebview that can be scrollable with the webview content.

Does anyone knows how to do that?
I tried using a scrollview with the toolbar and webview but no success.

My last chance was creating an overlay UIView and pass the touches methods to the uiscrollview, but that does not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView contains a UISCrollView, you just need to add a UIWebView to your view, then a UIToolBar.

```
UIWebView* wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:.....];
[yourView addSubview:wv];
UIToolBar* tb = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:.....];
[yourView addSubview:tb];
[wv release];
[tb release];
```

Comment: I have already tried that. The toolbar will stay put while the content will scroll, and besides that, the webview content would need to have it's frame changed or the toolbar will stay above the content